# Reorganizing an array using an empty return array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of arrays, each corresponding to a different value pulled from an API. I need to create a new array from the old one, with certain values' locations changed.

Here's what I have so far (in a function that takes an array of arrays called worksheetArray):

```
let ret = [];

let index = 0;
for (let element of worksheetArray) {
  ret[index][0] = ''; // Blank
  ret[index][1] = element[15] // Location
  ret[index][2] = element[0] // Team Name
  ret[index][3] = element[4] // Resource
  ret[index][4] = element[5].split(' ')[0] // From Date 
  ret[index][5] = element[5].split(' ')[1] // From Time
  ret[index][6] = element[6].split(' ')[0] // To Date
  ret[index][7] = element[6].split(' ')[1] // To Time  
}
```

This returns the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

What am I doing wrong here? How do I let my return array be assignable like this?

Thanks!

Comment: `ret[index] = []`? Also I doubt that `index` should stay the same during your loop. You'd better use `return worksheetArray.map(element => { … })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert a new sub-array into `ret` and increment the index after at the end of each loop:

```
let ret = [];

let index = 0;
for (let element of worksheetArray) {
  ret[index] = [];
  ret[index][0] = ''; // Blank
  ret[index][1] = element[15] // Location
  ret[index][2] = element[0] // Team Name
  ret[index][3] = element[4] // Resource
  ret[index][4] = element[5].split(' ')[0] // From Date 
  ret[index][5] = element[5].split(' ')[1] // From Time
  ret[index][6] = element[6].split(' ')[0] // To Date
  ret[index][7] = element[6].split(' ')[1] // To Time  
  index += 1;
}
```

An easier solution would be to create the sub-array, and push in a single expression:

```
const ret = [];

for (let element of worksheetArray) {
  ret.push([
    '', // Blank
    element[15], // Location
    element[0], // Team Name
    element[4], // Resource
    element[5].split(' ')[0], // From Date 
    element[5].split(' ')[1], // From Time
    element[6].split(' ')[0], // To Date
    element[6].split(' ')[1] // To Time  
  ]);
}
```

Or use `Array.map()`:

```
const ret = worksheetArray.map(element => [
  '', // Blank
  element[15], // Location
  element[0], // Team Name
  element[4], // Resource
  element[5].split(' ')[0], // From Date 
  element[5].split(' ')[1], // From Time
  element[6].split(' ')[0], // To Date
  element[6].split(' ')[1] // To Time  
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an array inside of the array for using nested indices.

```
let ret = [[]];
```

Or assign an array to the index

```
let ret = [];

let index = 0;
for (let element of worksheetArray) {
    ret[index] = [
        '', // Blank
        element[15] // Location
        element[0], // Team Name
        element[4], // Resource
        element[5].split(' ')[0], // From Date 
        element[5].split(' ')[1], // From Time
        element[6].split(' ')[0], // To Date
        element[6].split(' ')[1] // To Time  
    ];
}
```